# Connecting text and graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tkz-euclide, path-clipping

The idea was shamelessly stolen from: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/connecting-text-and-graphics/

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\tikzstyle{na} = [baseline=-.5ex]

Nec no appareat persecuti \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-anode);, ea meis labitur honestatis nec. 

Nisl indoctum delicatissimi ad nam, adolescens intellegam dissentiet pri no, facete assueverit in nam. Sed ne odio tale suscipit, ex vide rationibus percipitur mea. Ea diceret periculis dissentiet nam, ne duo novum graece. 

\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \tkzInit[xmin=-0.5, xmax=5.5, ymin=-0.9, ymax=3.5]
        \tkzClip
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/C, 3/3/A, 5/0/B, 1/3/a, 5/3/b}
        \tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[below left](C){$C$}
        \draw (1,3.2) node {\textit{Euclides' line}};
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.8](a,A,C){$1$}
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](a,A,C)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](B,C,A)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](b,A,B){$2$}
        \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.5 cm](B,A,b)
        \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.5 cm](A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawLine[add=1 and 1](A,a)
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
        \path[->,red,thick] (s-anode) edge [bend left] (C);
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It works (at least on my machine) and produces this: 
[image]

Obviously,

```
    \tkzInit[xmin=-0.5, xmax=5.5, ymin=-0.9, ymax=3.5]
    \tkzClip
```

spoils the arrow. After I comment it, it also works, but produces this: 
[image]

This is clear why: `tkz-euclide` requires some space for constructions and this space is supposed to be cut (as far as I understand it). But the line still doesn't go outside the picture. So this (`\tkzClip`) is not the reason. What do I do wrong? I want to connect a random word in the text with a random point on the diagram (as in the link). Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to put the arrow in a separate picture. You need the `overlay` option for the picture, as shown in the example, but you don't want that for the main picture.

Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated and it is unwise to use `figure` with just the `h` option (and probably ineffective - it only means 'here, if possible'). If you need a caption, use `\captionof` from `caption` or `capt-of`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,caption}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{% \tikzstyle is deprecated
  every picture/.append style={remember picture},
  na/.style = {baseline=-.5ex},
}

Nec no appareat persecuti \tikz[na] \coordinate (s-anode);, ea meis labitur honestatis nec.

Nisl indoctum delicatissimi ad nam, adolescens intellegam dissentiet pri no, facete assueverit in nam. Sed ne odio tale suscipit, ex vide rationibus percipitur mea. Ea diceret periculis dissentiet nam, ne duo novum graece.

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-0.5, xmax=5.5, ymin=-0.9, ymax=3.5]
    \tkzClip
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/C, 3/3/A, 5/0/B, 1/3/a, 5/3/b}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below left](C){$C$}
    \draw (1,3.2) node {\textit{Euclides' line}};
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.8](a,A,C){$1$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](a,A,C)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](B,C,A)
    \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](b,A,B){$2$}
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.5 cm](B,A,b)
    \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.5 cm](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawLine[add=1 and 1](A,a)
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[->,red,thick] (s-anode) edge [bend left] (C);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \captionof{figure}{Caption}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: overlaid arrow]

Note that the `tikz-mark` library provides `\tikzmark{}` and sub-nodes for this kind of purpose.

Comment: I would put the additional `tikzpicture` right after the `tikzpicture` of the image. This avoids that TeX's line and page breaking is disturbed by the zero box (option `overlay`) and the additional `tikzpicture` cannot move accidentally to the next page.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Like this? Thanks.

Comment: Rather this: `\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}\begin{tikzpicture[overlay] ... \end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek It isn't obvious to me that losing the caption is great either, but that seems sensible even so.

Comment: Then use a `minipage` to keep the `tikzpicture`s together with the caption, see my updated [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335425/16967).

Answer (score 4):

The red arrow at the end of `tikzpicture` needs option `overlay`. Otherwise TikZ would take the coordinates into account for the bounding box of the picture.

The clipping can be limited via a scope:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-euclide,caption}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{% \tikzstyle is deprecated
  every picture/.append style={remember picture},
  na/.style = {baseline=-.5ex},
}

Nec no appareat persecuti\tikz[na]\coordinate(s-anode);,
ea meis labitur honestatis nec.

Nisl indoctum delicatissimi ad nam, adolescens intellegam dissentiet pri no,
facete assueverit in nam.  Sed ne odio tale suscipit, ex vide rationibus
percipitur mea.  Ea diceret periculis dissentiet nam, ne duo novum graece.

\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \tkzInit[xmin=-0.5, xmax=5.5, ymin=-0.9, ymax=3.5]
      \begin{scope}
        \tkzClip
        \tkzDefPoints{0/0/C, 3/3/A, 5/0/B, 1/3/a, 5/3/b}
        \tkzLabelPoint[above](A){$A$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[below right](B){$B$}
        \tkzLabelPoint[below left](C){$C$}
        \draw (1,3.2) node {\textit{Euclides' line}};
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=-0.8](a,A,C){$1$}
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](a,A,C)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5](B,C,A)
        \tkzLabelAngle[pos=0.7](b,A,B){$2$}
        \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.5 cm](B,A,b)
        \tkzMarkAngle[arc=ll,size=0.5 cm](A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawPolygon[very thick](A,B,C)
        \tkzDrawLine[add=1 and 1](A,a)
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
      \end{scope}
      \path[overlay,->,red,thick] (s-anode) edge [bend left] (C);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{Caption}
  \end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]